# El tipo o el nombre del espacio de nombres 'WebForm1' no existe en el espacio de nombres 'myApp' (¿falta alguna referencia de ensamblado?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, .net, aspx

estoy empezando con .net y quiero una ventana nueva nueva en un proyecto que me han pasado, le he dado doble click agregar nuevo elemento y aquí no se muy bien cual poner, de momento he puesto el formulario web con página maestra, y me genera esto: (aspx)

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/SiteMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="myApp.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <h1><%=prueba %></h1>
</asp:Content>
```

y en el .aspx.cs tengo esto:

```
using GuardasWeb.bbdd;
using GuardasWeb.control;
using GuardasWeb.model;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace myApp
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string prueba = "okey";
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Pero al compilar la aplicación me salta solo la pantalla en blanco sin la variable que he definido y en los errores del visual studio me sale el que he puesto en el título, alguien sabe como puedo solucionar esto?? Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Es una vista Parcial?

Comment: Lo siento, pero no se muy bien a que te refieres, simplemente en un proyecto que me han dado en aspx, le he dado click derecho sobre el archivo del proyecto y he creado el formulario  web con página maestra

Comment: Aparte ese error salta porque no tienes incluido el namespace en tu página principal, añadiendo en ella `using myApp.WebForm1;` debería de solucionartelo

Comment: En que archivo se debería de poner eso?

Comment: No se si en aspx se permite (Yo estoy especializado en asp.net) pero en mi caso si se lo añado al controlador o en la propia vista, en la vista con poner `@using myApp.WebForm1;` a mi me funciona, creo que en aspx podría ser `<%@using myApp.WebForm1;%>`

Comment: Okey, pero esto en que archivo?? en el web.config? o donde exactamente?? ya que las otras vistas no tienen nada similar a eso, tienen esto en la cabecera pero no me funciona:

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/SiteMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="miVista.aspx.cs" Inherits="GuardasWeb.miVista" %>

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116875/discussion-between-yandrak-and-nicolas-onate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas incluir el namespace usando la directiva [`Import`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/eb44kack(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

Si lo haces al principio del aspx:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="myApp" %>
```

En el momento de ejecutar

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/SiteMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="myApp.WebForm1" %>
```

encontrará el espacio de nombres el cual tienes declarado.

Comment: No, no me funcionó, me salta este error
CS0138: A 'using namespace' directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'WebForm1' is a type not a namespace. Consider a 'using static' directive instead

Comment: He editado la respuesta, en teoria añadiendo al namespace unicamente myApp ya no debería saltarte ese error

Comment: Nada, me dice que el tipo o el nombre del espacio de nombres webform1 no existe en el espacio de nombres myApp

Comment: vaya... y si incluyes system te sigue ocurriendo? por eso de ser una clase parcial

Comment: no entiendo a que te refieres con lo incluid system??

Comment: webform1 es una clase parcial de `System.Web.UI.Page` tal vez por eso esté fallando

Comment: He reiniciado y ya me funciona, no entiendo el motivo

Comment: La cache XD si te ha funcionado agradecería que marcases la respuesta como correcta

Comment: okey, sin problema